# falla al instalar firebase

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, firebase, npm

trate de instalar firebase y firestore en un proyecto de react+vite
pero al ejecutar npm install firebase
empieza a descargar pero marca los paquetes como deprecated
al finalizar no agrega a package.json la dependencia firebase  pero si crea la carpeta y me arroja el siguiente fallo
npm install firebase

up to date, audited 1089 packages in 4s

106 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

5 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

ya trate con borrar la carpeta de node modules y luego npm install  para luego volver a intentar pero sin exito
tambien intente borrar el cache de npm pero sigue marcando deprecated
intente con npm audit fix y fix --force, el primero no realiza ninguna accion visible y el segundo se le antoja bajarme de 10.0.0(actual) a 8.6.8  al hacerlo sigo con el mismo problema

Comment: En cuanto a borrar la caché o la carpeta de módulos, no va a hacer nada por más veces que lo intentes. La nota que ves se relaciona a las vulnerabilidades que encuentra NPM en el paquete que instalaste, si son extremadamente serias, es mejor optar por otras opciones porque tu app puede verse comprometida por malware o errores de programación. Ahora que si intentas forzar a NPM a borrar estas vulnerabilidades, en caso de que funcione, el paquete o toda la app puede dejar de funcionar, tal vez porque dependían del malware que tenía dos funciones: vulnerar la app, y usar una fachada.